# I need to pull a first name from a full name during an append

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

So I've got a bunch of excel spreadsheets with different column headers and different formatting. I need all of them imported into an Access DB that I've been working with.

So I've essentially imported them all as separate tables and then consolidated, by appending them all, to one final table. In doing so I've encountered an issue. I need to pull every customer's first name, but on one spreadsheet FULL_NAME is the only column I can pull it from.

The problem is this...the format is like "John Michael Doe, MD"...which is a headache when I only need to pull John.

I tried the following expression as an append field

```
Left([strName],InStr([strName],” “)-1)
```

It kind of worked. What ended up happening is that it assigned EVERY first name to EVERY existing record. So I already have 492 records in the table I was appending to and there were 200 fields in this one, so I ended up with nearly 100,000 records. NOT FUN.

Is there a way around this?

**Edit:** Append query from comment:

```
INSERT INTO Consolidated_Data ( [Physician_First Name], [Physician _Last Name], Degree ) 
SELECT Left([Full Name],InStr([Full Name],' ')-1) AS PullFirst, 
       Source_OddName.[Last Name], Source_OddName.Degree 
FROM Consolidated_Data, Source_OddName
```

Comment: Please add the full SQL of the append query (?) you tried to your question.

Comment: I used the design wizard with minimal to no SQL of my own.

Comment: That is not a problem, just switch the query to SQL view and copy/paste the SQL text into your question.

Comment: INSERT INTO Consolidated_Data ( [Physician_First Name],     [Physician _Last Name], Degree )
    SELECT Left([Full Name],InStr([Full Name],' ')-1) AS PullFirst,    Source_OddName.[Last Name], Source_OddName.Degree
    FROM Consolidated_Data, Source_OddName;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easy fix is to just import it as normal... then do an UPDATE to get the first name from the already existing Full Name column. The append or INSERT statement should have worked so something is going on to create the additional records. But if you are not into figuring out why these additional records are being populated, or are just in a rush then the UPDATE Query should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that since some of the tables had the separated first name, your consolidated final table has a first name field. If you can go back to your 492-record table, simply create an update query where the FirstName column is updated to the expression you used above, with strName being replaced by the FullName column name.  If you want to be a little more sophisticated and not mess with the rows that already have a correct first name, simply add a criteria on the query where the FirstName column is "Is Null".